# Exception when parsing Java 16 bytecode with ASM library

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to parse bytecode from Java 16 (bytecode version 60) using the [ObjectWeb ASM](https://asm.ow2.io). I've written the following code:

```java
@Test
void parseBytecode() {
    try (InputStream stream = this.getClass()
         .getClassLoader()
         .getResourceAsStream("MethodByte.class")) {
         //MethodByte.class has 60 version (Java 16)
        new ClassReader(stream).accept(new ClassPrinter(), 0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private class ClassPrinter extends ClassVisitor {
    protected ClassPrinter() {
        super(Opcodes.ASM9);
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I'm getting an `IllegalArgumentException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:262)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:180)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
   at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:287)
```

Version of ASM library is `9.5` (from `pom.xml`):

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
  <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
  <version>9.5</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, it's worth mentioning that I checked the `MethodByte.class` lies in the correct place. I printed its content to ensure that it is reachable in the test.

From my understanding, ASM 9 should support java 16. I suspect the error might be due to the ASM version I'm using, and its incompatibility with Java 16 bytecode, so I tried `Opcodes.V16` instead of `Opcodes.ASM9` and it didn't help.

Also I tried to parse the bytecode with 52 version (Java 8) and it didn't help either.

Has anyone encountered this before?

---

**Update:** How I get `MethodByte.class`.

I'm using `maven` to build project and run the tests. So, I have the next pipeline:

1. I create a java class with the next content:

```java
package org.eolang.jeo;

public class MethodByte {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(method());
        System.out.println("passed");
    }
    static byte method() {
        return 52;
    }
}
```

2. I run `mvn clean compile` in order to build that class. I use the next maven configuration properties for that:

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

3. Then I copy that class under resource directory:

```
cp target/classes/org/eolang/jeo/MethodByte.class src/test/resources/.
```

4. Finally I run tests and get the exception which I mention above.

Comment: Does it work for classes compiled in an earlier version?

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. You did not even mention the exact ASM version use or show the source code for the compiled code.

Comment: @Olivier I tried to run one more example with 52 version (Java 8) and exception is the same.

Comment: @kriegaex I added a bit of context. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: [That path](https://gitlab.ow2.org/asm/asm/-/blob/ASM_9_5/asm/src/main/java/org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.java?ref_type=tags#L262) is only taken when it is not a valid class file.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Do you know how I can check "validity"? I tried to use `javap` and it parses bytecode successfully

Comment: Debugging. Did you try to set a breakpoint at the location where the exception is thrown? What is the value of the tag? What index is it? What does `javap` say about that constant pool index?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Location where the exception is thrown:

`currentCpInfoOffset` = `10`
tag (`classFileBuffer[currentCpInfoOffset]`) = `-65`
Actually the first twelve bytes are negative:
`[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 0, 0, 0, 60, 0, 41, 10, 0,  +more]`

Comment: And what about the index? What does javap say about the constant pool at that index?
Also, a class file should start with `0xCAFEBABE`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `javap` constant pool entry: `#10 = Utf8               java/lang/System`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn `hexdump -n 16 -C MethodByte.class ` gives me: `00000000  ca fe ba be 00 00 00 3c  00 29 0a 00 02 00 03 07`

Comment: This does not look right to me. The hexdump does not match the contents of the array you showed, for some reason. The hexdump looks like a valid class file, the array does not.

Comment: What was unclear about my comment? An MCVE is meant to be a **complete reproducer**. "A bit of context" does not do the job here, I am afraid. Where is the class file you are trying to parse or the source code you compiled to create it? This is not a discussion forum where problems are meant to be debated in multiple iterations. Just ask a clear question and be happy to get a straight, spot-on answer.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I added content of the `MethodByte` class and steps which I perform. Maybe this will help?

Comment: @kriegaex I tried to keep the question as small as possible at the cost of incompleteness. So, I added source code of the file to make the example fully complete. Hope it will help. Thank you four your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Johannes Kuhn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/845414/johannes-kuhn) mentioned, the binary representation of the original class didn't match the byte array passed into the `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader` class. The root of the problem lies in the [Maven Resource Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) mechanism. To put it simply, Maven triggers the `resources:3.3.1:testResources` goal during the `generate-test-sources` phase, which replaces placeholders in resource files with actual values. When Maven attempts to apply this filtering to binary files, it can encounter encoding issues, leading to the exception I mentioned in my question.

While the `src/test/resources` folder contained the correct bytecode, it was corrupted when I ran the tests (using `mvn clean test` command), subsequently causing the `IllegalArgumentException`.

To address this, I excluded `.class` files from filtering:

```xml
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.class</include>
      </includes>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

With this configuration, everything now works as expected without exceptions.

Comment: I am glad you found the root cause of your problem. See? That is exactly, why I asked for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which up to date you still did not provide. The problem is a Maven problem, but you only provided a POM snippet in your question.

Comment: Actually, in this case the problem sits in front of the computer anyway, IMO: You do not copy class files into the resource directory, with or without filtering. They do not belong there. Whatever your reason to do so might be, you did not explain it. You could still use `getResourceAsStream` on a class from the regular class path. Maybe you want to stop the class being discovered by the class loader, only to later inject it via ASM anyway. But if you would not load it from anywhere, it also would not be loaded until you need it in ASM. Anyway, congrats that your trick works now. 